# Get value in a row on click and pass it to popup

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I need to get the value in a row of a table on click and display it in popup

HTML:

```
<md-data-table-container>
    <table md-data-table class="md-primary" md-progress="deferred">
        <thead md-order="query.order" md-trigger="onorderchange">
            <tr>
                <th name="Task To Be Done"></th>
                <th name="Office"></th>
                <th name="Due Date"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-click="showAlert($event)">
            <tr ng-repeat="dessert in desserts.data" ng-click="showAlert($index)" flex-sm="100" flex-md="100" flex-gt-md="auto">
                <td>{{dessert.task}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>{{dessert.due_on}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</md-data-table-container>
```

JS:

```
$scope.desserts = {
    "count": 6,
    "data": [{
        "task": "Frozen yogurt",
        "type": "Ice cream"
    }, {
        "task": "Ice cream sandwich",
        "type": "Ice cream"
    }, {
        "task": "Eclair",
        "type": "Pastry"
    }, {
        "task": "Cupcake",
        "type": "Pastry"
    }, {
        "task": "Jelly bean",
        "type": "Candy"
    }, {
        "task": "Lollipop",
        "type": "Candy"
    }, {
        "task": "Honeycomb",
        "type": "Other"
    }]
};
$scope.showAlert = function (index) {
    $scope.obj = $scope.desserts.data[2];
    $scope.task = $scope.obj.task;
    alert($scope.task);
    console.log($scope.task);
};
```

issue in my code is that i could get the value on the array which i have specified ".data[2]". Actually when i click a row in my table i need that value to be displayed to popup "sweetAlert". is there any solution

Comment: This isn't very clear. You have a deserts array, yet don't show it, you have a click calling an $index but no repeat around it. Where does sweet alert come into it? You never call or use it? How do you think someone could possibly tell you what is wrong. Create a plunkr or jsfiddle with your code.

Comment: check my updated code

Comment: Added an answer. I do not know what you mean by "sweetAlert".

Comment: It worked. How it get to know the location without specifying by an index, can u explain me

Comment: actually i am trying to integrate this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGXWWp?editors=101 with alert   https://www.ludu.co/lesson/how-to-use-sweetalert  here i got that sweetalert

Comment: You can pass $index through if you need it, it can be dangerous is all. You can get the index from the item by using : var idx = scope.desserts.data.indexOf(dessert); in the showAlert method.

Comment: I updated answer with a link about avoiding $index. Glad it's working for you. Please consider marking my answer as a solution. All the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pass the `$index`, as this can be a bit dangerous if the underlying data changes, and in this case it just forces you to re-get the item from the array.

Pass the actual item you want to display back to the alert.

```
<tr ng-repeat="dessert in desserts.data" ng-click="showAlert(dessert)" flex-sm="100" flex-md="100" flex-gt-md="auto">
                <td>{{dessert.task}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>{{dessert.due_on}}</td>
            </tr>
```

Don't assign to scope unless you really need it elsewhere.

```
$scope.showAlert = function (dessert) {
   alert('Task:' + dessert.task);
   // if you're just using a variable in this function, declare it locally
   var dessertType = dessert.type;
   console.log(dessertType);
};
```

See an example of $index causing issues:

http://codeutopia.net/blog/2014/11/10/angularjs-best-practices-avoid-using-ng-repeats-index/comment-page-1/