# AngularJS ng-click: How to pass row data to modal pop up textboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to pass data information from any row clicked to the modal pop up textbox.

Here is my code, I don't know how to implement that.

This is a popup example  http://jsfiddle.net/92z54z04/1/, how can i pass value to the popup

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in myData | filter: searchBox" ng-click="openEdit(item)">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="checkbox2" />
        <label for="checkbox2" class="css-label mac-style">&nbsp;</label>
    </td>
    <td><a>{{item.Name}}</a></td>
    <td style="text-align: right;">{{item.IsActive ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you post your modal pop up code?

Comment: You can pass the entire 'item' object if you want. It's a javascript variable like any other. Your openEdit() function needs to support this

Comment: I have not create the openEdit() function because i don't know how to implement it to get and pass value from the row and pass it to the textbox

Comment: which modal popup you are using? add some relevant code

Comment: Too broad. The task is very simple but you need to provide details.

Comment: This is an example i found here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731575/get-value-in-a-row-on-click-and-pass-it-to-popup       but instead of displaying it on alert()  i want to pass the value to textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `$scope.selectedItem` inside your `openEdit` function.

And assign `ng-model="selectedItem.<your_property>"` to text-box inside modal.

I have create a plunker code, It may help you.
https://plnkr.co/edit/tEzmex?p=preview

Comment: not working.

  If you can create an example with plnkr such that when edit is clicked there is a popup passing all data to each field.

This is an example of a popup  http://jsfiddle.net/92z54z04/1/    if you can edit and pass value to the popup

Comment: just created a plunker and updated my answer https://plnkr.co/edit/tEzmex?p=preview

Comment: Now it will work as per your requirement... Just updated that plunker code... using that `modal` directive. Also replaced template with templateUrl for improvement.